# Powershell: Finding and appending values to columns between two has tables and two csv files

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am going to try to break this simply...

## The problem description

2 csv files (destination file gets its fields automatically filled in by other csv files)

I have a source csv file with 3 rows containing:

```
sourceColumn1,sourceColumn2,sourceColumn3,sourceColumn4,sourceColumn5,sourceColumn6,sourceColumn7    ,sourceColumn8    ,sourceColumn9,sourceColumn10,sourceColumn11,sourceColumn12,sourceColumn13,sourceColumn14,sourceColumn15,sourceColumn16
sourceValue1 ,value2a      ,value3a      ,value4a      ,value5a      ,             ,value7a          ,sourceValueFound1,value9a      ,              ,              ,value12a      ,              ,              ,              ,
value1b      ,value2b      ,value3b      ,value4b      ,value5b      ,sourceValue2 ,                 ,sourceValueFound2,value9b      ,              ,              ,              ,value13b      ,              ,              ,
value1c      ,             ,value3c      ,value4c      ,value5c      ,sourceValue3 ,                 ,sourceValueFound3,value9c      ,              ,              ,              ,              ,              ,sourceValue3  ,
```

I have a destination csv file (before code is run) with 3 rows containing:

```
"destinationColumn1","destinationColumn2","destinationColumn3","destinationColumn4","destinationColumn5","destinationColumn6"
"value1aa"          ,"value2aa"          ,"value3aa"          ,"sourceValue1"      ,"value5aa"          ,"AdValueFound1"
"value1bb"          ,"sourceValue2"      ,"value3bb"          ,"value4bb"          ,"sourceValue2"      ,"AdValueFound2"
"value1cc"          ,"sourceValue3"      ,"value3cc"          ,"value4cc"          ,"value5cc"          ,"No SourceValueFound"
```

## The End Goal

I wish to add a column `destinationColumn7` in the destination file with the where(values -ne $null) in  `sourceColumn8` from the source file.

Matching the correct values is done by finding the `sourceValue#` from the source file and matching it with the `sourceValue#` in the destination file.

So the destination file, should look like this:

```
"destinationColumn1","destinationColumn2","destinationColumn3","destinationColumn4","destinationColumn5","destinationColumn6" ,"destinationColumn7"
"value1aa"          ,"value2aa"          ,"value3aa"          ,"sourceValue1"      ,"value5aa"          ,"AdValueFound1"      ,"sourceValueFound1"
"value1bb"          ,"sourceValue2"      ,"value3bb"          ,"value4bb"          ,"sourceValue2"      ,"AdValueFound2"      ,"sourceValueFound2"
"value1cc"          ,"sourceValue3"      ,"value3cc"          ,"value4cc"          ,"value5cc"          ,"No SourceValueFound","sourceValueFound3"
```

## What I have tried so far

To do this, I am using the following code...

```
Write-Host "Creating hash table with columns `"sourceColumn1`" and `"sourceColumn8`" From $sourceCsvFile"
$FirstHashTable = @{}
Import-Csv $sourceCsvFile | ForEach-Object {
    $FirstHashTable[$_.sourceColumn1] = If ($_.sourceColumn8) {$_.sourceColumn8} Else {'No SourceValueFound'}}
Write-Host "Complete."

Write-Host "Appending new destinationColumn7 column from hash table"
(Import-Csv $destinationCsvFile) |
    Select-Object -Property *, @{n='destinationColumn7';e={
    If ($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn4)){
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn4]
    } ElseIf ($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn5)){
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn5]
    } ElseIf ($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn1)){
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn1]
    } Else {
        'No MatchFound'
    }}} | Export-Csv "$destinationCsvFile-Temp" -NoType
Move-Item "$destinationCsvFile-Temp" $destinationCsvFile -Force
Write-Host "Complete."
```

The result of the destination file:

```
"destinationColumn1","destinationColumn2","destinationColumn3","destinationColumn4","destinationColumn5","destinationColumn6" ,"destinationColumn7"
"value1aa"          ,"value2aa"          ,"value3aa"          ,"sourceValue1"      ,"value5aa"          ,"AdValueFound1"      ,"sourceValueFound1"
"value1bb"          ,"sourceValue2"      ,"value3bb"          ,"value4bb"          ,"sourceValue2"      ,"AdValueFound2"      ,"No SourceValueFound"
"value1cc"          ,"sourceValue3"      ,"value3cc"          ,"value4cc"          ,"value5cc"          ,"No SourceValueFound","No SourceValueFound"
```

As we can see, this did not append the last 2 rows with the `sourceValueFound#` under `destinationColumn7`. Instead they are `No SourceValueFound`.

Next I noticed the `sourceValue#` was in a different column in the source file, and the `sourceValueFound#` was not `$null`

So I made a change to the code...

```
$sourceCsvFile = 'C:\Temp\test1.csv'
$destinationCsvFile = 'C:\Temp\test2.csv'

Write-Host "Creating hash table with columns `"sourceColumn1`" and `"sourceColumn8`" From $sourceCsvFile"
$FirstHashTable = @{}
Import-Csv $sourceCsvFile | ForEach-Object {
$FirstHashTable[$_.sourceColumn1] = If ($_.sourceColumn8) {$_.sourceColumn8} Else {'No SourceValueFound'}}
Write-Host "Complete."

Write-Host "Creating hash table with columns `"sourceColumn6`" and `"sourceColumn8`" From $sourceCsvFile"
$SecondHashTable = @{}
Import-Csv $sourceCsvFile | ForEach-Object {
$SecondHashTable[$_.sourceColumn6] = If ($_.sourceColumn8) {$_.sourceColumn8} Else {'No SourceValueFound'}
}
Write-Host "Complete."


Write-Host "Appending new destinationColumn7 column from hash table"
(Import-Csv $destinationCsvFile) |
    Select-Object -Property *, @{n='destinationColumn7';e={
    If (($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn4)) -and ($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn4) -ne 'No SourceValueFound')) {
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn4]
    } ElseIf (($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn5)) -and ($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn5) -ne 'No SourceValueFound')){
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn5]
    } ElseIf (($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn2)) -and ($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn2) -ne 'No SourceValueFound')){
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn2]
    } ElseIf ($SecondHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn4)){
        $SecondHashTable[$_.destinationColumn4]
    } ElseIf ($SecondHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn5)){
        $SecondHashTable[$_.destinationColumn5]
    } ElseIf ($SecondHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn2)){
        $SecondHashTable[$_.destinationColumn2]
    } Else {
        'No MatchFound'
    }}} | Export-Csv "$destinationCsvFile-Temp.csv" -NoType
Write-Host "Complete."
```

The result of the destination file:

```
"destinationColumn1","destinationColumn2","destinationColumn3","destinationColumn4","destinationColumn5","destinationColumn6" ,"destinationColumn7"
"value1aa"          ,"value2aa"          ,"value3aa"          ,"sourceValue1"      ,"value5aa"          ,"AdValueFound1"      ,"No SourceValueFound"
"value1bb"          ,"sourceValue2"      ,"value3bb"          ,"value4bb"          ,"sourceValue2"      ,"AdValueFound2"      ,"sourceValueFound2"
"value1cc"          ,"sourceValue3"      ,"value3cc"          ,"value4cc"          ,"value5cc"          ,"No SourceValueFound","No SourceValueFound"
```

Now it adds the `sourceValueFound#` in the 2nd row of the destination file, but the 3rd row is still `No SourceValueFound` for `destinationColumn7`.

Anyone who can help me fill in what I am missing would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this, i was not skipping the keys containing values of `'No SourceValueFound'`, because I was using `($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn4) -ne 'No SourceValueFound')` instead of `($FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn4] -ne 'No SourceValueFound')`

Then I had to add this to the other 3 ElseIf statements to ensure all non `'No SourceValueFound'` values were checked first, before assuring `'No SourceValueFound'` was correct.

```
$sourceCsvFile = 'C:\Temp\test1.csv'
$destinationCsvFile = 'C:\Temp\test2.csv'

Write-Host "Creating hash table with columns `"sourceColumn1`" and `"sourceColumn8`" From $sourceCsvFile"
$FirstHashTable = @{}
Import-Csv $sourceCsvFile | ForEach-Object {
    $FirstHashTable[$_.sourceColumn1] = If ($_.sourceColumn8) {$_.sourceColumn8} Else {'No SourceValueFound'}}
Write-Host "Complete."

Write-Host "Creating hash table with columns `"sourceColumn6`" and `"sourceColumn8`" From $sourceCsvFile"
$SecondHashTable = @{}
Import-Csv $sourceCsvFile | ForEach-Object {
    $SecondHashTable[$_.sourceColumn6] = If ($_.sourceColumn8) {$_.sourceColumn8} Else {'No SourceValueFound'}}
Write-Host "Complete."


Write-Host "Appending new destinationColumn7 column from hash table"
(Import-Csv $destinationCsvFile) |
    Select-Object -Property *, @{n='destinationColumn7';e={
If (($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn4)) -and ($FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn4] -ne 'No SourceValueFound')) {
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn4]
    } ElseIf (($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn5)) -and ($FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn5] -ne 'No SourceValueFound')){
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn5]
    } ElseIf (($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn2)) -and ($FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn2] -ne 'No SourceValueFound')){
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn2]
    } ElseIf (($SecondHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn4)) -and ($SecondHashTable[$_.destinationColumn4] -ne 'No SourceValueFound')){
        $SecondHashTable[$_.destinationColumn4]
    } ElseIf (($SecondHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn5)) -and ($SecondHashTable[$_.destinationColumn5] -ne 'No SourceValueFound')){
        $SecondHashTable[$_.destinationColumn5]
    } ElseIf (($SecondHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn2)) -and ($SecondHashTable[$_.destinationColumn2] -ne 'No SourceValueFound')){
        $SecondHashTable[$_.destinationColumn2]
    } ElseIf ($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn4)) {
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn4]
    } ElseIf ($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn5)){
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn5]
    } ElseIf ($FirstHashTable.ContainsKey($_.destinationColumn2)){
        $FirstHashTable[$_.destinationColumn2]
    } Else {
        'No MatchFound'
    }}} | Export-Csv "$destinationCsvFile-Temp.csv" -NoType
Write-Host "Complete."
```

Works now...